# sort dates in python according to hour, day, month

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, date

I have a string array of dates with this formula:

```
array(['2018-01-01 02:00:00 +01:00', '2018-01-01 04:00:00 +01:00',
    '2018-01-01 05:00:00 +01:00', ..., '2018-12-31 21:00:00 +01:00',
    '2018-12-31 22:00:00 +01:00', '2018-12-31 23:00:00 +01:00'],
   dtype='<U26')
```

I want to sort the dates by month and by hour, e.g:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00 +01:00
2018-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00
2018-01-01 02:00:00 +01:00
```

and so on.
I am using this mini code:

```
time1=time.sort()
```

but the sorting gives the month and all the values of an hour before moving to the next hour.
Is there a way to sort these dates by hour according to each day of every month?

Comment: Nope.. The date format is different

Comment: Obviously you need to use an appropriate format specifier for `strptime`, not just copy what is used in the other question.

Comment: yeah i did that for my type of data and it didn't work

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show how you have tried to use `strptime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z") for ts in timestamps]
dates.sort()
sorteddates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z") for ts in dates]
```

Do double confirm if the DateTime format corresponds. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp